# Brain performance suppliments

Tags: brain, concentration, b-12-supplements, short-term-memory-loss, multi-vitamin

My 27 years old brain lacks concentration and  memory, mood to perform daily task is lazy.

I used to have a test most of the vitamins are ok except D and B complex Below average a little bit.

Which supplements do you suggest me to take in order to get rid of mind Absent, and bad memory Also increase concentration, in terms of best Supplements brand and what should i take?

Comment: Don't take any supplements. Do physical exercise (an often underrated but very important factor for brain performance) and mental exercises.

Comment: Don't forget to consider psychological health.  You just listed 3 common symptoms seen in depression, ADHD, or anxiety...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Narusan's comment on exercise, it's important to consider diet too. Sometimes a lack of concentration and mental alertness can result from lower-than-usual energy levels, which can in turn be caused by poor dietary choices.

NHS Choices stresses that eating well (as in a healthy, balanced diet) is preferable to taking supplements when trying to boost or maintain energy levels: http://www.nhs.uk/Livewell/tiredness-and-fatigue/Pages/energy-mythbuster.aspx